# Is maximizing a definite integral equivalent to maximizing without the integral?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Is the maximization problem
$$\max_D \int_x p_d(x)\log(D(x)) + p_g\log(1-D(x))dx,$$
given some $p_d(x)$ and $p_g(x)$, equivalent to (removing the integration)
$$\max_D p_d(x)\log(D(x)) + p_g\log(1-D(x))?$$

After which solving for $D$ yields:
$$D^*=\frac{p_d(x)}{p_d(x) + p_g(x)}$$

Comment: @angryavian It does since D is a function of x in the objective function.

Comment: Are there any constraints on what $D$ can be? My earlier comment was under the assumption that the maximization is over a finite class of functions $D$, but it seems you are allowed to consider any function $D$?

Comment: no, there are no constraints.

Comment: Then yes, what you have done is fine.

Comment: what/where is this objective function for/from? is $D$ a discriminator function?